# Customize Chart js dataset data

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js, bar-chart

This is what my chart looks like:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/PnDt6.png

I need to show the value in the tooltip in time format like 00:55:25.
This chart needs to plot time of different chronometers.

This is my code.

```
   var ctx = document.getElementById("myBarChart");
    var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            labels: ['activity 1', 'activity 2', 'activity 3'],
            datasets: [{
                label: "Value",
                backgroundColor: "rgba(2,117,216,1)",
                borderColor: "rgba(2,117,216,1)",
                data: [545, 3600, 3211],
            }],
        },
        options: {
            scales: {
                xAxes: [{
                    time: {
                        unit: 'month'
                    },
                    gridLines: {
                        display: false
                    },
                    ticks: {
                        maxTicksLimit: 3
                    }
                }],
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        min: 0,
                        max: 36000,
                        stepSize: 3600,
                        beginAtZero: true,
                        callback: function (label, index, labels) {
                            console.log(label)
                            switch (label) {
                                case 3600:
                                    return '01:00:00';
                                case 7200:
                                    return '02:00:00';
                                case 10800:
                                    return '03:00:00';
                                case 14400:
                                    return '04:00:00';
                                case 18000:
                                    return '05:00:00';
                                case 21600:
                                    return '06:00:00';
                                case 25200:
                                    return '07:00:00';
                                case 28800:
                                    return '08:00:00';
                            }
                        }
                    },
                }],
            },
            legend: {
                display: false
            }
        }
    });
```

How is it possible to change the value in the dataset to time format or only in the view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have prepared a [demo here](https://codepen.io/sbsatter/pen/ExZPdZQ). The convert function is taken from [here](https://code.labstack.com/HVdZZYqH). You can modify Chart JS tooltips as follows:

```
function convert(time) {   
    // Hours, minutes and seconds
    var hrs = ~~(time / 3600);
    var mins = ~~((time % 3600) / 60);
    var secs = ~~time % 60;

    // Output like "1:01" or "4:03:59" or "123:03:59"
    var ret = "";
    if (hrs > 0) {
        ret += "" + hrs + ":" + (mins < 10 ? "0" : "");
    }
    ret += "" + mins + ":" + (secs < 10 ? "0" : "");
    ret += "" + secs;
    return ret;
}

var ctx = document.getElementById("myBarChart");
    var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            labels: ['activity 1', 'activity 2', 'activity 3'],
            datasets: [{
                label: "Value",
                backgroundColor: "rgba(2,117,216,1)",
                borderColor: "rgba(2,117,216,1)",
                data: [545, 3600, 32110],
            }],
        },
      options: {
        responsive: true,
            tooltips: {
                callbacks: {
                    label: function(context) {
                        let str = convert(context.yLabel);
                        return str;
                    }
                }
            },
            scales: {
                xAxes: [{
                    time: {
                        unit: 'month'
                    },
                    gridLines: {
                        display: false
                    },
                    ticks: {
                        maxTicksLimit: 3
                    }
                }],
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        min: 0,
                        max: 36000,
                        stepSize: 3600,
                        beginAtZero: true,
                        callback: function (label, index, labels) {
                            return convert(label);
                        }
                    },
                }],
            },
            legend: {
                display: false
            }
        }
    });
```

From [ChartJS docs](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/configuration/tooltip#label-callback), it suggests wrapping tooltips in plugins object inside options, but it didn't seem to work with version provided by the CDN in the demo. So you may need to wrap with plugins.